# What is the way to transform my class component into function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

What is the way to transform my class component into function component?
in my example I try to display search bar and i need do it with function component instead class component.

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { Table, Row, Rows } from 'react-native-table-component';
 
const ExampleOne = (props) =>{ 
      const [tableHead, settableHead] = useState(['Head', 'Head2', 'Head3', 'Head4'])
      const [tableData,settableData] = useState([
        ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
        ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        ['1', '2', '3', '456\n789'],
        ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
      ])
  
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#c8e1ff'}}>
          <Row data={tableHead} style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.text}/>
          <Rows data={tableData} textStyle={styles.text}/>
        </Table>
      </View>
    ) 

export default ExampleOne 
 
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, padding: 16, paddingTop: 30, backgroundColor: '#fff' },
  head: { height: 40, backgroundColor: '#f1f8ff' },
  text: { margin: 6 }
});
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to know? Are you looking for general guidelines or just someone to do the work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try as the following:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';

const App = () => 
  const [search, setSearch] = useState({
     text: ''
  });

  return {
    return (
      <SearchBar
        placeholder="Type Here..."
        onChangeText={ (search) => setSearch({ text: search }) }
        value={search.text}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I suggest the following documentation to read in more details: [Using the State Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

**+1 addition:**

I would consider using `const [search, setSearch] = useState('')` only for your search state because it is shorter. In the mentioned way you can store more information in the `search` state but it's up to you which fits for your situation better.

Comment: Now you have a completely different question from the original one, probably easier to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You use React Hook and change your class-based component to functional component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { SearchBar } from "react-native-elements";

const App = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  const updateSearch = (search) => {
    setSearch(search);
  };

  return (
    <SearchBar
      placeholder="Type Here..."
      onChangeText={(i) => updateSearch(i)}
      value={search}
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';


export default App = () => {
    const [search, setSearch ] = useState('');

    return(
        <SearchBar
        placeholder="Type Here..."
        onChangeText={ search => setSearch(search) }
        value={search}
         />
    );
}
```